# use policy as condition on query builder laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have this code

```
    $userSpacesTimelines = $user
                ->spaces()
                ->select('spaces.id', 'spaces.uuid', 'spaces.slug', 'spaces.privacy_type')
                ->with('timeline:id,owner_type,owner_id')
                ->get();

            $filteredSpace = $userSpacesTimelines->filter(function ($space) {
                return auth()->user()->can('viewTimeline', $space);
            });
```

the bottleneck is on filtering spaces based on viewTimeline policy, and that policy requires lot of tables and 100+ line. so the question is can I use policy as a condition inside my query builder, something like
`$user->whereCan('viewTimeline')->spaces();`

thank in advance for the help

Comment: In Laravel, you can't directly use a policy as a condition inside a query builder like you would with Eloquent scopes. Policies are designed to define authorization rules, and they aren't meant to be used for filtering or querying data. For policy anyway you have to fetch the space from database

Comment: you can filter the data similarly to your how your policy is implemented, but not use the policy itself